# typo3 phpunit TestingFramework

Tags: testing, tdd, phpunit, typo3

I'm trying to do test-driven development in `typo3` 4.7.8, a PHP based CMS.
 Using the `TestingFramework` class provided by the `phpunit` extension, I have problems [following the tutorial documentation](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/phpunit/3.5.14/view/1/3/) provided with the `phpunit` extension (regarding the `TestingFramework` class)

Here I have this trivial unit test

```
/**
 * @test
 *
 */
public function fake_frontend_can_be_instantiated() {

    $this->testingFramework->createFakeFrontEnd(16); // uid=16
    $expectedResult = 1;
    $actualResult = $this->testingFramework->hasFakeFrontEnd();
    $this->assertEquals ( $expectedResult, $actualResult );
}


Result: 
 fake frontend can be instantiated
! Error in test case fake_frontend_can_be_instantiated
File: .../typo3_src-4.7.8/t3lib/class.t3lib_db.php
Line: 730
mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given
```

The same happens when I call `createFakeFrontEnd`() with empty args. 
When I enable the dbal extension (database abstraction layer) this is the output:

```
File: ...typo3-4.7.8/typo3_src-4.7.8/typo3/sysext/dbal/class.ux_t3lib_db.php
Line: 1546
mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given
```

I really like to use the TestingFramework, because I have a whole lot of frontend users to create,, and I want to test each user's login credentials before we send out notification emails.

Comment: Can you try to use the most recent version of TYPO3 like 6.1.3 or 4.7.14? Additionally, your assertion might break, because `hasFakeFrontEnd()` returns a boolean, not an integer. BTW: there is also an `assertTrue()` method inside PHPUnit, which makes it a little more readable. Can you post the whole stacktrace of the php error you get?

Comment: how do you run the tests?

Comment: It is not an option for me to set up a newer version, and I run the tests from within the backend as an admin user.